# Using getpass with Sublime Text

Tags: python, text, sublimetext3, getpass

Like the title says I am tryin gto use the getpass library with sublime text (and SublimeREPL.) When I run a simple piece of code, I get nothing but a blank screen in the sublime terminal and the REPL terminal. Is there any way to get getpass to work with sublime text? I ran the same code in powershell python and it worked just fine.

```
import getpass
psswd = getpass.getpass(prompt = 'Password:')
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  Sublime text provides the basic terminal functions, not an actual complete terminal.

Because some of the essential components of terminals are not reproduced in REPL or Sublime You cannot run `getpass` correctly from them.

You are best off sticking with the CMD or PowerShell.

Likewise for the Python IDLE:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> psswd = getpass.getpass(prompt = 'Password:')

    Warning (from warnings module):
      File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\getpass.py", line 100
        return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
    GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
    Warning: Password input may be echoed.
    Password:
```

---

The Python documentation warns you of this:

> If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

Comment: Nitpick: they are all terminal emulators, a "real terminal" would be *a physical video terminal* like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Thank you,  I have edited my answer, does it look better now?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good to know for future use though!